# NgFor in a Tailwind Accordion

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, ngfor

I have been trying to show an array of posts with the tailwind accordion but it is not working as expected. The accordion will show the headings when a post is created but it would not expand to show the post's content. I have also changed the attributes of data-accordion-target to dynamically target the body using the "ngfor: index as i". Also I am not sure where to place the structural directive because it is kind of showing two separate accordions.

```
<div id="accordion-collapse" data-accordion="collapse">
  <div *ngFor="let post of posts; index as i">
    <h2 id="accordion-collapse-heading-1">
      <button type="button"
        class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 font-medium rtl:text-right text-gray-500 border border-b-0 border-gray-200 rounded-t-xl focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 gap-3"
        attr.data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-{{i}}" aria-expanded="true"
        attr.aria-controls="accordion-collapse-body-{{i}}">
        <span>{{post.title}}</span>
        <svg data-accordion-icon class="w-3 h-3 rotate-180 shrink-0" aria-hidden="true"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
          <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
            d="M9 5 5 1 1 5" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="accordion-collapse-body-{{i}}" class="hidden" attr.aria-labelledby="accordion-collapse-heading-{{i}}">
      <div class="p-5 border border-b-0 border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900">
        <p class="mb-2 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">{{post.content}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template seems fine and the accordion works fine for me.

Did you install and configure the Flowbite js library that is required for the accordion?

From the [Tailwind Angular docs](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/angular/):

Install Flowbite:

```bash
npm install flowbite
```

Update your Tailwind config to include Flowbite:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
    "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js" // 1. add this line
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin') // 2. add this line
  ],
}
```

Init Flowbite in your component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'web-app';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    initFlowbite();
  }
}
```

[Working example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qy6hsa?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Note that I made some small adjustments to the template:

1. I changed `<h2 id="accordion-collapse-heading-1">` to `<h2 id="accordion-collapse-heading-{{i}}">`.
2. I added the code below to the button to make sure only the first button has rounded corners at the top (to prevent it from looking like there are separate accordions like you said):

```html
[ngClass]="i === 0 ? 'rounded-t-xl' : 'rounded-none'"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will get to configuring flowbite into my project, I may have missed some steps. Will update if it works! Thank you!

Comment: Hello Rens, I have done the steps to configure Flowbite into the project. The accordion only works when I am using a hardcoded array to iterate through. It does not seem to work with dynamic data, I have posted a new SO question with more details about it, will really appreciate if you can help! :)

Comment: Could you please mark the current question as answered, so it can help others too? I'll take a look at your new question when I'm free.